# get value of value attribute usind id in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get value of value attribute using id attribute of html tag.

```
<p id='abc' value='xyz'>123456</p>
```

and my javascript is

```
var a=document.getElementById(abc).innerHTML; 
alert(a);
```

this gives me alert "123456" but I want alert function should display me "xyz". How can I do these. I also tried getElementById(abc).value this returns nothing.

OR is there ant way to make tag which is doesn't display on browser. I don't want to display 123456 on browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
var a = document.getElementById('abc').getAttribute('value'); 
alert(a);
```

Note that the argument `abc` in your question is not enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
alert(document.getElementById("abc").getAttribute("value"));
```

DOM Element getAttribute() Method - Get the target attribute value of a link:

#### DEMO

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var a=document.getElementById("abc").getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: Err: `abc` is not enclosed in quotes

Comment: @Салман -- Nicely spotted.